# Save slurm job information automatically

Tags: slurm

I am looking for a way to save job information provided by sacct automatically to some file. So far I have included an sacct call in my job batch script, but then the state is always "RUNNING".

Is there a way to automatically call sacct *after* the job ended/died?

The only thing that came to my mind was to submit a second job that depends on the first and then calls sacct, but this is obviously not a good option.

Comment: On the contrary, running a second job with a dependency on the first (_e.g._, `--dependency=afterany:firstjobid`) seems like _the_ way to do it when you don't have access to the Slurm logs or config files. Is there any particular reason you are avoiding this method?

Comment: I saw two problems: 1. The cluster admins strongly discouraged the submission of jobs that do basically nothing to limit stress on the scheduler (in the same spirit they only provide a cached version of squeue that only updates every 30 sec) 2. After running my job arrays my Fair Share is very low so I can't be sure that the second job is running before the info provided by sacct gets purged (queues can be long here).

Comment: Okay, I understand. Is [`at`](http://man.cx/at) an option on your cluster nodes? Although I forget exactly how to do this with Slurm, if you could get an interactive login on a node, inspect `/usr/lib/cron/at.allow` (possibly just `/etc/cron.allow`) and `/usr/lib/cron/at.deny` to determine. I wouldn't count on it—since Slurm sort of obviates the need for `at` / `batch`. But if `at` for some reason _were_ allowed on the nodes, you could run your `sacct` command at some designated time interval _after_ the cluster job proper has already terminated.

Comment: Have you gotten weird/wrong values for the fields other than state?  Otherwise, if the `sacct` command is run as the last one of the submission script, you might simply ignore the state field

Answer (score 0):

You can set a file to store job completion data with `JobCompLoc` in `slurm.conf`. (We parse that file to send extra information in the job completion emails, and it includes (I think) everything that you get from `sacct`).

Comment: Interesting! Unfortunately I seem not to have access to the `JobCompLoc` folder, nor can I modify `slurm.conf` as I am on a cluster. Should have mentioned that.